# Problem with passing javascript variable to PHP variable via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a variable from javascript to a PHP variable on the same page using AJAX.

I've been looking through all the post I could find and even though is been asked a few times before (how to pass javascript variable to php via ajax), I can't get it to work..

Here is what I tried from what I read from other posts. But it is not working.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('#submitfakta').live('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        var idAttr = $(this).attr('value');
                        //alert($(this).attr('id'));
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'profile.php',
                            data: idAttr : idAttr 
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                alert("success!");
                            }
                        });
                    });
    }
  });


  </script>
```

This is my javascript code alone without using AJAX. 
It is working correctly for getting my variable using javascript. But it lacks the part that sends the variable to a php variable on the same page. 
By looking through others post I tried using AJAX as my example above, but as already mentioned without luck.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('#submitfakta').live('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        var idAttr = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(idAttr);
    } 
  });


  </script>
```

My PHP code trying to print my variable:

```
<?php
  $idAttr = $_POST['idAttr'];
  echo $idAttr;
  ?>
```

Comment: You need to provide the value to `data` as an object: `data: { idAttr: idAttr }`. Voting to close as a typo. Also note jQuery 1.5.2 is *very* outdated (you should be using 1.12.1 at least) and also `live()` has been deprecated. Use the delegated signature of `on()` instead.

Comment: Danger: jQuery 1.5.x is past end of life and has known security issues. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I now tried upgrading and changing out live() with on(), but now my javascript without the ajax does not work. 
I would appreciate if you don't close my post? I'm trying to understand how this work, and by changing my data typo is not making it work either.

Comment: If you are having issues with upgrading the version of jQuery I would suggest starting a new question, being sure to include details of any console errors and all code relevant to that error.

Comment: My main issue is getting my variable from my javascript (which the javascript itself is working without the AJAX) and somehow pass this variable via AJAX to my PHP variable. 

I'm doing this project local, and the security issues Quentin is pointing out is not an issue as much as to getting the problem solved my post here is suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my HTML & JS Code!

```
    <div id="submitfakta" value="abdulrehman" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: red;"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('#submitfakta').live('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        var idAttr = $(this).attr('value');
        //alert($(this).attr('id'));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'profile.php',
            data: {idAttr : idAttr },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert("success! " + data);
            }
        });

    }
  });
  </script>
```

AND HERE IS MY profile.php CODE:

```
<?php 
echo $_POST["idAttr"]; exit;
```

Comment: It does not work. Thanks for offering your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: How is it possible, it should must work. Tell me what happened ? did you get any error or something? Show me please so I can help you

Comment: Just nothing happens now when I hover on my button. 

I'm using the javascript to hover on a button, get the value and the value is what I want to get in a php variable so I can use it for a SQL query. 

If I use my script without the ajax, when I hover on the button I get an alert box showing the value.

Comment: Means you don't need help anymore right ? You have done by your own with another trick ?

Comment: No, I still need help with getting the variable from javascript into a php variable.

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console ? @Chao1920

Comment: @Ari No errors. The first part of my javascript is still working: showing an alert box of the correct value when I hover a button. 

But  $_POST['idAttr'] is empty.

Comment: maybe the problem lies within your php code. Could you possibly update your post to include the php code as well ? @Chao1920

Comment: @Ari I have now. Appreciate your help

Comment: Check I have edited my answer and its working perfect on my side. I just created an index.html file and put my html div with attribute value and then place your js code. Then I have created a profile.php file and its working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

try to send data like this(data have to be a plain object or string)

```
data: {idAttr : idAttr}
```

and get in php

```
$idAttr = $_POST['idAttr']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the data as

```
data: {var1: value1, var2 : value2}
```

You have the following, which is incorrect

```
data: idAttr : idAttr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass that data like in jquery,

```
data : "idAttr ="+ idAttr;
```

And on PHP Side

```
$idAttr = $_POST['idAttr'];
```